# How could i implement automatic YT opening?

Tags: c++, youtube

Titile basically.

How could i implement the opening of my browser and then youtube and a specific music.

Ty in advance.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Isn't that what the default page is about?

Comment: no ty im not here to make posts pleasable to your eyes but to answer my questions. i feel like it is a simple question that hasnt nessecerally been answered before. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, this should work to open your default browser:

```
ShellExecute(
    NULL,                   // handle to parent window
    "open",                 // pointer to string that specifies operation to perform
    "http://youtube.com/",  // pointer to filename, folder name or resource
    NULL,                   // pointer to string that specifies executable-file parameters
    ".",                    // pointer to string that specifies default directory
    SW_SHOWNORMAL           // whether file is shown when opened
);
```

Comment: It works perfectly ty!

Comment: Great! You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Use system(); to run any bash commands, so use:

```
system("Browserpath http://youtube.com/");
```

Obviously, replace Browserpath with the path to your browser.

Comment: It does not work, and it says: 'Browsepath' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You missed the last sentence: _replace Browserpath with the path to your browser_. Btw, what OS are you using?

Comment: Ohhhh, my bad. Okay. Im using Win  8.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `system()` function:
    `system("start https://www.youtube.com");`
If you use the command "start" Windows will open your default browser, if you want to open with another browser you have to replace `start` with your browser's path.

Comment: That's nicer than my answer. Didn't know that.